# Pytest not showing test results in the terminal window

Tags: python, terminal, pytest

I'm trying to run some tests by invoking the `pytest` command at the command line in a directory containing tests. At the end, however, I see only how many tests passed or failed, but I don't see which ones, or the traceback the failed tests produced (see screenshot below).

Before I was seeing these things, and I don't recall changing anything in Pytest's configuration. What could be the issue?

[image]

**Update**

What is even more strange is that when I run some of the test scripts which I'm quite sure were displayed to yield test failures when run with `pytest` individually, the tests pass:

```
kurt@kurt-ThinkPad:~/dev/clones6/ipercron-compose/test$ pytest test_api.py
====================== test session starts =======================
platform linux2 -- Python 2.7.12, pytest-3.0.5, py-1.4.32, pluggy-0.4.0
rootdir: /home/kurt/dev/clones6/ipercron-compose/test, inifile: 
plugins: flask-0.10.0
collected 5 items 

test_api.py .....

==================== 5 passed in 4.20 seconds ====================
kurt@kurt-ThinkPad:~/dev/clones6/ipercron-compose/test$ pytest test_furion.py
====================== test session starts =======================
platform linux2 -- Python 2.7.12, pytest-3.0.5, py-1.4.32, pluggy-0.4.0
rootdir: /home/kurt/dev/clones6/ipercron-compose/test, inifile: 
plugins: flask-0.10.0
collected 6 items 

test_furion.py ......

==================== 6 passed in 7.84 seconds ====================
kurt@kurt-ThinkPad:~/dev/clones6/ipercron-compose/test$ pytest test_furion2.py
====================== test session starts =======================
platform linux2 -- Python 2.7.12, pytest-3.0.5, py-1.4.32, pluggy-0.4.0
rootdir: /home/kurt/dev/clones6/ipercron-compose/test, inifile: 
plugins: flask-0.10.0
collected 4 items 

test_furion2.py ....

=================== 4 passed in 12.91 seconds ====================
```

Could there be some kind of difference between calling the tests with the `pytest` command or the `pytest [filename]` command?

Comment: Do you see output with `pytest --color=no` ?

Comment: What happens if you run `python -m pytest` ?

Comment: What is the exact issue you are seeing? @user94154

Comment: It looks like some of your tests are writing control keys sequence in terminal. Try  `pytest > out.txt` and then check what is in out.txt.

Comment: It's probably your terminal color scheme. Change themes and see if you notice a difference, or highlight some text. You can also run with `pytest --color=no`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
pytest -h
```

to show all of the info about possible flags and options.
But the eisiest way to add more info to your tests adding **-v** flag, **--verbose**         increase verbosity.

```
pytest your_test.py -v
```

f.i. if you have print() statement in your tests adding **-s** shows all of the results while running.

```
pytest your_test.py -v -s
```

Answer (score 0):

I would install [pytest-html](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytest-html/). That way potential problems with terminal output can be fixed.